# Forcing retransmissions with NFQUEUE

Tags: tcp, iptables, netfilter

for a project of mine I am trying to manually trigger a retransmission for certain packets in a TCP Flow.
So far I found NetFilterQueue a good way to do this, but now I am stuck.
I have a working version that handles every packet, so I can modify/accept/drop it.
So this part is working.

At the Moment, when I find a packet that I want retransmitted, I set a mark and use NF_REPEAT to reinject the packet into the queue.
I thought that with doing so I would send the packet out and send a copy of it through the queue again, where it would be NF_ACCEPT'ed cause of its mark. Effectively doing a retransmission of that packet.

But it turns out this does not work as I hoped it would...

So my question is:
Is there a way I could use NFQueue to accomplish my retransmissions?

Or is there another way to do such a thing?

Comment: Since the edits to my post are not saved at the moment, please excuse the missing "Hello" and introduction in my question

Comment: From what I understand you are trying to induce packet duplication, not retransmission.

Comment: @FormerNcp well... Theoretically I want to do a retransmission, but wouldn't a duplicated packet just look like a retransmission to the receiver?

Comment: Yes, my objection is to the use of the word retransmission. In the context of TCP a retransmission implies that the sender has deemed the original packet lost. The receiver sees the packet as a duplicate. If you want to do real retransmissions you need to induce packet loss. Would this link help? https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/netem

Comment: My goal is that the receiver sees the packet as a real retransmission and I want him to see both packets. Wireshark calls it a "Spurious Retransmission". Netem looks good, but I need to duplicate only very specific packets and not "1% of them".   
I might try to block the ACK packets to make the sender believe his packet got actually lost.